# jQuery UI accordion in IE < 9 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI Accordion in IE 8 and faced with an issue "unexpected call method or property access" at this line

{this.nodeType===1&&this.insertBefore(a,this.firstChild)}

I'm using jQuery-1.7.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I've placed a hidden input in a wrong place.  Modern browsers are too smart! :)